# Dancer2 Authentication

Tags: perl, authentication, dancer

I'm trying to use the Dancer2 plugin: [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible) with my own authentication provider because there is an existing one in the project I'm working on.

I have adapted [the given example](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Example), however I need to pass a couple of parameters to both the `authenticate_user` and `users` subroutine.  The parameter is dynamic, so I can't add it via the configuration file.

I have an inelegent method to pass it in with the username as a string (concatenated) and then split it inside the `authenticate_user`, but this won't work with the `users` subroutine.  And this just isn't the right way to do it.

I also tried passing it as a regular parameter, like

```
sub authenticate_user {
   my ($self, $username_course, $password, $realm,$param) = @_;
```

but this didn't work (not sure why), and it won't work for `users`, which no parameters.

I've thought that since this is a Dancer2::Plugin that I could leverage some of that, but not exactly how to adapt the existing Plugin.  This is what I've tried:

```
package Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Provider::Test;

use Moo;
with "Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Role::Provider";

has authen_param => (is => 'rw');

plugin_keywords 'set_param';  # this fails compilation


sub set_param {
  my ($self,$p) = @_;
  $self->authen_param($p);
}

sub authenticate_user {
  my ($self, $username, $password) = @_;

  # use authen_param to authenticate
}
1
```

Comment: FYI, not many people follow the dancer tag, so you'll get more eyes on your Dancer questions if you also include the perl tag.

Comment: What are the extra parameters you need to pass in and where do they come from? Does the user enter them?

Comment: The parameter is just a string that will determine some additional info needed to authentication the users.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. I asked those questions because you can't pass additional parameters to `authenticate_user` without making changes to Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible itself, so you will need another way of getting that "additional info". How you do that depends on what exactly your unspecified string *is* and where it comes from.

Comment: I added some code above to revive this question.

Comment: It appears that I can use the session to store the information that I need.  I need to make sure that I store the parameter in the session and then can retrieve it using `$self->plugin->dsl->session->{param_name}`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I can use the session to store the information that I need.  I need to make sure that I store the parameter in the session and then can retrieve it using `$self->plugin->dsl->session->data->{param_name}`.